# How to use remote openstreetmap osrm server for USA

Tags: r, openstreetmap, server, open-source-routing-machine

How can I use a remote osrm server to calculate driving distances in the USA (or North America). If at all possible, I would really like to avoid having to set up my own local server.

I am basing my MWE off of the answer by SamR in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997208/how-to-speed-up-code-that-finds-shortest-driving-time-between-two-sets-of-points). I am trying to find the shortest driving times between two sets of points. As a baseline:

```
library(osrm)

source <- data.frame(
    id = 1:3,
    latitude = c(45.37306, 45.37306, 45.37306),
    longitude = c(-108.41307, -108.11307, -107.81307)
)

dest <- data.frame(
    id = 4:5,
    latitude = c(44.3500, 38.6800), 
    longitude = c(-68.2100, -109.5700)
)

osrmTable(
    src = source[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    dst = dest[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    osrm.profile = "car", measure=c("duration", "distance"),
    osrm.server = "https://routing.openstreetmap.de/")

$durations
      1    2
1 154.1 2365
2 154.1 2365
3 154.1 2365

$distances
       1       2
1 132471 3014230
2 132471 3014230
3 132471 3014230

$sources
        lon      lat
1 -10.46702 52.10941
2 -10.46702 52.10941
3 -10.46702 52.10941

$destinations
         lon      lat
1 -10.424649 51.88574
2  -9.497727 38.78069
```

These results do not make much sense. I then try a different server (`https://router.project-osrm.org/`), but the results (not shown) are exactly the same as above.

```
osrmTable(
    src = source[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    dst = dest[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    osrm.profile = "car", measure=c("duration", "distance"),
    osrm.server = "https://router.project-osrm.org/")

options(osrm.server = "https://router.project-osrm.org/")
osrmTable(
    src = source[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    dst = dest[c("longitude", "latitude")],
    osrm.profile = "car", measure=c("duration", "distance"))
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a different `osrm.server` that I can use?

Comment: You're likely better off asking directly at the github repository. I personally think the package could do a better job helping users get set up with their own server
https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/issues/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem comes when the latitudes (or longitudes) of at least two points are identical or nearly identical. If one changes them slightly so that they are a bit different, then it seems to work (in other words, it works for the USA). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331431/osrmtable-give-incorrect-results-when-two-latitudes-or-longitudes-are-identical. With that said, I am not sure why this happens or if there is another solution.